# Attempting to trigger modals with h2 elements to overlay an animating background. Doesn't work, can someone help see where I went wrong?

Tags: javascript

As it says in my title, I am trying to trigger modals with javascript by clicking on h2 elements.

When I use inspector to change the modal display mode from none to visible I can see the modal on top of everything else. But clicking on the h2 elements doesn't seem to trigger this action so I assume its a problem with my javascript.

Can anyone help me out here? Can't seem to get it and I'm sure its something dumb.

Here is my code.

**Html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Jacob Truax Portfolio</title>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts.css">
  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>We are a magazine. This is a test.</p>
  </div>

</div>

<!-- Button triggering color change -->
  <div id="myBtn" class="Btn">
  <button></button>
  </div>

<!-- main content -->
<div class="main">
  <ul>
    <li class="fnup">fn-up</li>
    <li class="about">about</li>
    <li class="issue">issue 0</li>
    <li class="contact">contact</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<!-- main-2 content overlaid on "main" -->
<div class="main-2">
    <h2 id="myButton" class="fnup2">fn-up</h2><br>
    <h2 class="about2">about</h2><br>
    <h2 class="issue2">issue 0</h2><br>
    <h2 class="contact2">contact</h2>
</div>

<!-- section with rotating 3d object -->
<section>
  <div class="face face-cover"></div>
  <div class="face face-spine"></div>
  <div class="face face-back"></div>
  <div class="face face-top"></div>
  <div class="face face-side"></div>
  <div class="face face-bottom"></div>
</section>

</body>

<script src="rotate.js"></script>
<script src="gradient.js"></script>
<script src="rotate-type.js"></script>
<script src="transition.js"></script>
```

**css**

```
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 5; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
    font-size: 2vw;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
/* End modal ============ */


body {
  background-color: #d22c1f;
  font-family:"Brrr", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 12vw;
  overflow: hidden;


  perspective: 1500px;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1600px) {
    body {
        font-size: 210px
    }
}

/* a {
  opacity: 0;
  color: rgba(102, 102, 102, 0);
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
} */

/* the main contet is in 3d space and rotates slightly with the cursor */
.main {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
}

li {
  text-shadow: 4px 4px 40px #000;
  color: rgba(102, 102, 102, .3);
  padding-left: 60px;
  top: -10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* main-2 is h2 texts overlaid on top of "main" in order to trigger modals */
.main-2 {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

h2 {
  opacity: 1;
  color: rgba(102, 102, 102);
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 60px;
  top: -10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* This button triggers the background color change */
div.Btn {
  position: fixed;
  line-height:0;
  font-size: 0px;
  right: 3vw;
  bottom: 3vh;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  background-image:  url(lib/frown.svg);
  opacity: 0.3;
  mix-blend-mode: overlay;
  z-index: 2;
}

div.Btn:hover {
  background-image:  url(lib/smile.svg);
  opacity: 0.3;
  mix-blend-mode: overlay;
}

button {
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  border: none;
  outline:none;
  background: transparent;
  border: none !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size:0;
}

/* section for rotating object following cursor */
section {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 75vw;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
  z-index: 1;
}

div.face {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-size: cover;
}

div.face-cover {
  width: 440px;
  height: 620px;
  background-image: url(lib/fn-up_Magazine_Cover.jpg);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) translateZ(15px);
}

div.face-side {
  width: 30px;
  height: 620px;
  background-image: url(lib/fn-up_Magazine_Side.jpg);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotateY(90deg) translateZ(220px);
}

div.face-spine {
  width: 30px;
  height: 620px;
  background-image: url(lib/fn-up_Magazine_Spine.jpg);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(220px);
}

div.face-top {
  width: 440px;
  height: 30px;
  background-image: url(lib/fn-up_Magazine_Top.jpg);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotateX(90deg) translateZ(310px);
}

div.face-bottom {
  width: 440px;
  height: 30px;
  background-image: url(lib/fn-up_Magazine_Bottom.jpg);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(310px);
}

div.face-back {
  width: 440px;
  height: 620px;
  background-image: url(lib/fn-up_Magazine_Back.jpg);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotateY(180deg) translateZ(15px);
}
```

**Javascript** 
rotate.js

```
document.addEventListener("mousemove", function (event) {
  const x = event.pageX
  const y = event.pageY
  const midX = x - window.innerWidth / 3.9
  const midY = y - window.innerHeight / 2

  const box = document.querySelector('section')

  //box.style.left = x + "px"
  //box.style.top = y + "px"

  box.style.transform = "rotateX(" + (midY * 0.35) + "deg) rotateY(" + (midX * 0.35) + "deg)"
  //box.style.transform = "rotateY(" + (midX * 0.4) + "deg)"
})
```

gradient.js

```
var angle = -20, color = "#2b2b2b", colors = "#000", font = "rgba(102, 102, 102, .3)", shadow = "4px 4px 40px #000";

var changeBackground = function() {
  angle = angle + .3
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = "linear-gradient(" + angle + "deg, " + colors + ", " + color + ", " + colors + ",  " + color + ",  " + colors + ",  " + color + ", " + colors + ",  " + color + ", " + colors + ",  " + color + ", " + colors + ", " + color;
  requestAnimationFrame(changeBackground)
}

var changeFont = function() {
  document.querySelectorAll('li').forEach(li => li.style.color = font);
}

var changeShadow = function() {
  document.querySelectorAll('li').forEach(li => li.style.textShadow = shadow);
}

changeBackground()
changeFont()
changeShadow();

document.querySelector('#myBtn').addEventListener('click', function () {
  color = (color != "#2b2b2b") ? "#2b2b2b" : "#f1f9d4";
  colors = (colors != "#000") ? "#000" : "#759ef3";
  font = (font != "rgba(102, 102, 102, .3)") ? "rgba(102, 102, 102, .3)" : "rgba(178, 117, 164, .3)";
  shadow = (shadow != "4px 4px 40px #000") ? "4px 4px 40px #000" : "4px 4px 40px #fff";
  changeFont()
  changeShadow();
})
```

rotate-type.js

```
document.addEventListener("mousemove", function (event) {
  const x = event.pageX
  const y = event.pageY
  const midX = x - window.innerWidth / 2
  const midY = y - window.innerHeight / 2


  const type = document.querySelector('.main')

  //box.style.left = x + "px"
  //box.style.top = y + "px"

  type.style.transform = "rotateX(" + (midX * 0.009) + "deg) rotateY(" + (midY * 0.009) + "deg)"
  //box.style.transform = "rotateY(" + (midX * 0.4) + "deg)"
})
```

transition.js (**the modal**)

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var button = document.getElementById("myButton");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
button.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: Are the JS run/executed after document loaded?

Comment: @TanvirAhmed Yes, why?